# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, symfony, command-line-interface

After changing PHP version from 5.3.3 to 5.4, my sever (Centos5) did not work.

Taking it back to 5.3.3, I get the following error message from the CLI (I'm using Symfony2) :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
'/usr/lib64/php/modules/newrelic.so'
- /usr/lib64/php/modules/newrelic.so: undefined symbol:
php_output_write in Unknown on line 0
```

I did a few workaround on solutions, none of them worked..

Comment: you have also to rebuild your modules, not only your php?

Comment: did you look [here](https://newrelic.com/docs/php/troubleshooting-your-installation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/newrelic-install
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Did the trick. I guess that the module newrelic were not reinstalled properly.

Thanks !